# I can't connect to my mysql glpi database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem with my code, I want to connect to my mysql glpi database but I have a launch error.
[This is a log of  mysql base of glpi]
[image: 1]

```
        'Charger Liste'

        ConnectionString = "server=10.14.242.190;port=3307;userid=root;database=GLPI;"

        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString
        conn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT * FROM glpi_computers"
        MessageBox.Show(Query)
    End If

End Sub
```

This is error : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Comment: Try adding an empty PW: `"server=10.14.242.190;port=3307;userid=root;pwd=;database=GLPI;"`. Also worth checking out: [https://www.connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Comment: The server IP doesn't even match what you have in the php configuration file. Are you sure those 2 target the same server ?

Comment: @NicolasMoreau the mysql server is installed locally on a physical server. My application is launched from my PC and therefore I am looking for the physical server which is at 10.14.242.190. Is my resonance good?